# Can this example prove that bode plot is not correct?

Tags: system

Bode plot implies that for a linear system, if the input is a sinusoidal signal, output of the system will also be a sinusoidal signal with same frequency but different amplitude and phase. Knowing input, we can estimated steady state output based on bode plot. Note that it states input and output have same frequency. But I found an example which seems doesn't match this rule.

The system is a simple mass-spring system,

[image]

For simplicity, set m=1kg, k=1N/m, then equation of motion is
[image]
If system input is F=sin(2t),
the output is x=(2/3)*sin(t)-(1/3)*sin(2t) by solving differential equation.

As can be seen, input has only one frequency component, but output has two frequency components, one is the natural frequency of the system, the other is the same as input frequency, and the two components are steady state rather transient. Obviously, in this case, the output can't be estimated using bode plot of the system.

I am not sure if people have realized this phenomenon, I was always sure about that input and steady-state output should have same frequency before I found this. Can this example prove that bode plot is not valid in some situations?

Comment: Interesting, we're relating mechanical springs and electrical oscillation :) This appears to be an undamped "signal".

Answer (score 2):

In standard form $$H(s)=\frac{\omega_n^2}{s^2+2\zeta\omega_ns+\omega_n^2}$$ your second order system $$H(s)=\frac{1}{(s^2+1)}$$ exhibits a damping ratio \$\zeta = 0\$ (no damping or an oscillator).

The main motivation (see the literature) for the construction of Bode Diagrams is that the terms in output corresponding to **negative real part poles** of a system will **vanish** at steady state (**which not apply for oscillators**). Even in these cases, the Bode diagram could still provide an interpretation for the presence of the two different frequency components on output. See the Bode Diagram below (magnitude only) for your system. At the frequency of 2 rad/s, the expected response occurs with a magnitude of 1/3. Now observe the peak, ie, the infinite gain at resonant frequency of 1 rad/s. Imagine that, at same time, there is an sinusoidal input of magnitude zero at this frequency (as it actually does), and that **infinite gain will cause the response to assume the finite value** which does not disappear. So you have both components in the output.

[image: Bode_Plot_Osc_Dirceu]

Answer (score 2):

Great question. I think a subtle mistake has led you to this paradoxical conclusion.

When you solved the second order differential equation, you would have arrived at a general solution of:

$$
x(t) = c_1sin(t) + c_2cos(t) - \frac{1}{3}sin(2t)
$$

where \$c_1\$ and \$c_2\$ are constants determined by initial conditions. It looks like you've assumed initial conditions of:

$$
x(0) = 0,\, \dot{x}(0) = 0
$$

to arrive at your \$\frac{2}{3}sin(t)\$ term. In fact, if that was the state of the system at initial time, then there would be a slight impulse and hence, a tiny broadband frequency component in the input to excite the resonance.

Instead, if you assume that the external \$F\$ is the only input to the system, then the initial conditions would be:

$$
x(0) = 0,\, \dot{x}(0) = -\frac{2}{3}
$$

Plugging those initial conditions in give you constants of \$c_1=0\$ and \$c_2=0\$ and thus a system response of just:

$$
x(t) = - \frac{1}{3}sin(2x)
$$

which only has frequency components that exist in the input.

We tend to gloss over the derivation and importance of the initial conditions when studying this material, which is why I think this question has caused some confusion. So thank you for bringing it up!

Comment: I don't think there is any paradox (or even confusion) in the OP question, which was about Bode Plot. Although the application is focused on the study of stable systems, Bode Plots attempts to describe the frequency response of transfer functions, which specifically admit null initial conditions. You picked up a particular initial condition to get only one component at the output.

Comment: Yeah, you got lulled into the OP's first mistake - confusing a Bode Plot with an LTI system. Probably more a synecdoche than being outright wrong. I think the premise "it states input and output have same frequency" and "input has only one frequency component" is the core of the matter, not the representation (Bode plot).

Answer (score 1):

Very interesting question. You have it right—we use Bode plots to get the steady-state response of a system to sinusoidal inputs.

In the system you have, the poles are on the imaginary axis (they have no real part). If it had the real part of poles on the left side of the s-plane, then the system's natural modes would vanish and the steady-state behavior would be described **100%** by the bode plot. That is, if the system's natural modes do not vanish, the bode plot would only give you part of the zero state solution but you'd ***still have*** ***to add*** the response due to the system itself. After all, you still have a ***linear*** system (linear differential equation) and its solution is ***superposition*** of the different outputs. For asymptotically stable systems, the transient terms will die out but your system is **marginally stable**—there are non-decaying terms.

In short, the bode plot is meaningless for unstable systems because there is no steady state. For marginally stable systems, at least the response does not grow unbounded as time increases. And for asymptotically stable systems, the steady state response is described completely by the bode plot. With that said, however, the math **does not** break: If you add the system's natural response to the one given by the bode plot's, you still get the total solution if the system is linear (superposition holds). This is true for unstable systems as well the only thing is that some part of the answer will grow unbounded and there is no such thing as steady state.

Now, let's put this into context. Say you have a system transfer function, \$H(\text{s})\$ and you have an input \$F(\text{s}\$). The steady state response is just the convolution of those (multiplication in Freq. domain). So you'd have:

$$ Y_{SS}=H(\text{s})F(\text{s})$$

Remember that \$H(\text{s})\$ has the poles of the system in its denominator, that is,

$$H(\text{s})=\dfrac{N(\text{s})}{\Delta (\text{s})} $$

Where the roots of \$\Delta (\text{s})\$ are the poles of the system. If \$F(\text{s})\$ is the transform of a sinusoidal function (say \$\cos(\omega _ot)\$ for example), then \$F(\text{s})=\dfrac{s}{s^2+\omega _o^2}\$ :

$$ Y_{SS}=H(\text{s})F(\text{s})=\dfrac{N(\text{s})}{\Delta (\text{s})}\cdot\dfrac{s}{s^2+\omega _o^2}$$

If you do partial fraction, you could re-write it as:

$$ Y_{SS}=\dfrac{A(\text{s})}{\Delta (\text{s})}+\dfrac{B(s)}{s^2+\omega _o^2}\tag1$$

The bode plot describes the second term (***that is what you are actually plotting***), the one with the B term in the numerator. The system's natural modes are described by the first term, the one with the A term in the numerator, which vanish for asymptotically stable systems.

If the real part of the roots of \$\Delta (\text{s})\$ are not negative, the first term in (1) will not vanish. So even though the Bode plot still gives you part of the solution, you still have to add the non-decaying part. The bode plot can't describe the whole response unless the first term in (1) tends to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Misunderstood assumptions:

**Verify, as one of these statements is untrue.**

- input has only one input frequency component.
- output has two frequencies  **

.

- The x component becomes stored spring energy.

  - If force, F has zero change in static force (DC) and the sine acceleration maintains this **x** value, then the response is only a single frequency of some amplitude and phase.
  - There is no excitation energy at resonance.
- If **x** changes, then the input has an effective Step function which is defined by a continuous spectrum of frequencies with a declining amplitude vs **f**.

  - The net result of spring-mass resonance is due to the frequency-amplitude component of the change in static force.
- As shown it is lossless and no damping so the resonant vibration is sustained.

**If x changes and force sin(2t) is applied, then conclusion is true.**  **